# Is it possible to nest if statement in for loop in Django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-class-based-views

I passed 2 context variables `{{ year_list }}` and `{{ current_year }}` into a django template. I am looping through the `{{ year_list }}` and checking if `{{ current_year }}` is in the `{{ year_list }}`.

```
{% each_year in year_list %}
  {% if each_year == current_year %}
   <li class="active"><a href="{{ each_year }}">{{ each_year }}</a></li>
  {% else %}
   <li><a href="{{ each_year }}">{{ each_year }}</a></li>
  {% endif %}
```

It doesn't seem to be working. None of the list item has `class='active'`. But it prints the correct value when I put `{{ each_year }}` and `{{ current_year }}` right after `{% each_year in year_list %}`

I am actually using Class Based View `YearArchiveView` and I want to have a list of years and high-light the current year.

```
class SomeYearArchiveView(YearArchiveView):
    queryset = Some.objects.all()
    date_field = 'some_date'
    make_object_list = True

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SomeYearArchiveView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['year_list'] = [2010, 2011, 2012]
        context['current_year'] = self.request.path.split("/")[2]
        return context
```

What did I do wrong? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Do the list items render at all?

Comment: BTW, of course it's possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In function `get_context_data` -

```
context['year_list'] = [2010, 2011, 2012]
context['current_year'] = self.request.path.split("/")[2]
```

The `year_list` values are `integer` whereas `current_year` value is `string`. That's why they are not matching in template. Do this in your code -

```
context['current_year'] = int(self.request.path.split("/")[2])
```

This should work

Comment: Yep. You are right. I thought all context variables are casted to string or repr() when they are rendered in the template. Thanks